# Bitnami wordpress htaccess.conf setup

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, bitnami

I am using xampp to develop a wordpress site using bitnami application installer all is fine at the moment except that there is no .htaccess file but instead they are using a htaccess.conf file. would i be able to create a .htaccess file in order to allow .svg mime type? or is there a way to do that with the htaccess.conf file?

I appreciate the help :)

Answer (score 4):

Bitnami developer here:

One of our main goals is to configure Bitnami applications in the most secure way. For this reason, we moved the configuration in the ".htaccess" files to the main application configuration files and set the "AllowOverride" option to "None" by default.

In this case, you have two options:

- Set the AllowOverride directive to All in xampp_dir/apps/wordpress/conf/httpd-app.conf and use the .htaccess files.
- Use xampp_dir/apps/wordpress/conf/htaccess.conf with the content of the .htaccess files that you have.

I hope it helps.